# Types of ScriptPubKey that can contain addresses

Tags: address, script

I'm trying to get the addresses from the `ScriptPubKey`s in each transaction (where possible). So far, I know of two patterns of `ScriptPubKey` where an address can be found:

**1. Pay-To-Pubkey**

```
04e70a02f5af48a1989bf630d92523c9d14c45c75f7d1b998e962bff6ff9995fc5bdb44f1793b37495d80324acba7c8f537caaf8432b8d47987313060cc82d8a93 OP_CHECKSIG
```

In this locking script, the code before `OP_CHECKSIG` is a public key, so that can be converted in to an address.

**2. Pay-To-Pubkey-Hash**

```
OP_DUP OP_HASH160 3d37cde30fdfcf29b2996a7ceefd220ba32c9f4b OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG
```

In this one, the code after `OP_HASH160` (and before the next `OP` code) is the hash160 of a public key, so that can be converted to an address also.

**Question:**

Are there any other patterns of `ScriptPubKey` where addresses can be found?

Or in other words, will I be able to capture every address by working on all non-opcodes *before* `OP_CHECKSIG`, and all non-opcodes *after* `OP_HASH160`?

Answer (score 1):

Technically, `pay-to-pubkey` doesn't have an address type. You can derive an address as if it were a `pay-to-pubkeyhash` scriptPubKey, but there is a subtle difference.

The other type you are forgetting is a `pay-to-scripthash` type. It's of the format

`OP_HASH160 <Hash160(redeemScript)> OP_EQUAL`

Then, you get a p2sh adddress by prepending the version byte and appending the checksum to `<Hash160(redeemScript)>`

Answer (score 1):

OP_1 [pubkey] OP_1 OP_CHECKMULTISIG